# Having multiple section with different color which have the same environment

Tags: sectioning, color

I'm having trouble changing the sections's colors. They all have the same environment rSection defined below :

```
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{ 
  \sectionskip
  \MakeUppercase{\bf #1} % Section title
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \begin{list}{}{ 
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}
```

But if I manage to set a specific color for this section, every sections will have the same color.. I tried

`\begin{rSection}{\protect\textcolor{ForestGreen} Education}`

but `xcolor` doesn't recognize this color but it does for basic text within the section..
How can I solve this ?

Comment: `ForestGreen` is a color named via `dvipsnames` or `svgnames`, so loading `\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}` should work. Or try `\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}` best right after `\documentclass{...}`

Comment: With dvipsnames, but I successfully changed the color to ForestGreen of the text within the section. But trying to change the section's title makes xcolor not recognizing any color.. mayne because capitalized letters ?

Comment: `\MakeUppercase` is responsible for this, for upper case of ForestGreen, i.e. FORESTGREEN, which is unknown of course. You may need a different interface to your section environment, pushing the color out of the `\MakeUppercase` argument.

Comment: Besides all: `\bf` is outdated. Use `\bfseries` instead

Comment: apart from uppercasing issues `\textcolor{ForestGreen} Education` is `\textcolor{ForestGreen}{E}ducation` and would just color E, was that intended?

Comment: Well, I deleted \MakeUpperCase and I will just write in Uppercase.. I don't know why this function even exists.. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Because you gave us no compilable code I can only guess what the commands `\sectionskip` and `\sectionlineskip` should do. I simply commented them in the following code.

You can define a second parameter carrying the color name for environment `rSection` like

```
\newenvironment{rSection}[2]{% 
% \sectionskip
  \color{#2}\MakeUppercase{\bf #1} % Section title
% \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \begin{list}{}{ 
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}
```

then you can use

```
\begin{rSection}{Education}{ForestGreen}
```

to get the green color.

Please see the following compilable code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\newenvironment{rSection}[2]{% 
% \sectionskip
  \color{#2}\MakeUppercase{\bf #1} % Section title
% \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \begin{list}{}{ 
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{rSection}{Education}{ForestGreen}
Text Text Text
\end{rSection}

\begin{rSection}{Education}{red}
Text Text Text
\end{rSection}

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

If your used class already defined the environment `rSection` simply create a new one `myrSection` in your preamble of your document with

```
\newenvironment{myrSection}[2]{% 
  \sectionskip
  \color{#2}\MakeUppercase{\bfseries #1} % Section title
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \begin{list}{}{ 
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}
```

and use it this way in your document:

```
\begin{myrSection}{Education}{ForestGreen}
Text Text Text
\end{myrSection}
```

Comment: Thanks you but the whole section have the color I defined, it's not what I wanted, sorry if I was unclear about that. Thanks anway ! Solved it :)